# upper bound for power series

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question:

Suppose that $f(z) = \sum_n^\infty a_nz^n$ is analytic for $|z| < R$ and is continous on $|z| = R$. Let $M = \sup_{|z| \leq R} |f(z)|$. Show that $|a_n|R^n \leq M$ for all $n$ and more generally that $\sum_n^\infty |a_n|^2R^{2n} \leq M^2$.

The first assertion follows from the Cauchy Integral Formula. However, I do not see how to incorporate the series in the second claim. There is a hint that says to consider $\int_{|z| = R} |f(z)|^2/z dz$.

Comment: Just take $I(r)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta, r < R$ and compute it explicitly integrating term by term (allowed by absolute convergence and then only diagonal terms have non-zero integral by periodicity) and let $r \to R$ noting that trivially $I(r) \le M^2$

Comment: How can I integrate term by term? Wouldn't I need to push the absolute value side inside the series (which messes with the series)?

Comment: $|f(re^{i\theta})|^2=f(re^{i\theta}) \bar f(re^{i\theta})=\sum a_n \bar a_m r^{n+m}e^{i(n-m)\theta}$ and all the terms with $n-m \ne 0$ integrate to zero

Comment: @Conrad. Are you allowed to let $r \to R$? We don't even know if the the series actually converges at $|z| = R$.

Comment: monotone convergence theorem applies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $r \in (0, R)$ you can apply Parseval's identity (see for example [Proof of Parseval's identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540446/proof-of-parsevals-identity)):
$$
  \sum_n |a_n|^2 r^{2n}  = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{it})|^2dt \le 
\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_0^{2\pi} M^2dt = M^2 \, .
$$
The conclusion $ \sum_n |a_n|^2 R^{2n} \le M^2$ then follows by taking the limit for $r \to  R$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer