# Suppose $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is analytic such that $|f|<2$. Also, suppose that $f''(0)=4i$. Find the value of $f(i/2)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Question: Suppose $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is analytic such that $|f|<2$.  Also, suppose that $f''(0)=4i$.  Find the value of $f(i/2)$.

Thoughts: If this was the first derivative, I feel like I could just use Schwarz-Pick, but being given the second derivative is throwing me off a bit.  I still feel like it is the "right track", because we are given the second derivative of $f$ at $0$, so it is (at least to me) suggesting something with Schwarz Lemma, but I can't quite get anything to come out nicely.  Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Comment: is $\mathbb{D}$ the open unit disk ?

Comment: yes, sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: I wonder if C-R could be used since we know its analytic. Like working backwards and we know if $f=u+iv$ then $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$

Comment: I wonder if Schwarz Lemma can be generalized to any maximum on the modulus of $f$

Comment: I thought of that, but I wasn't quite able to make anything work using C-R equations. 

Ahhh, I hadn't thought of trying to use maximum modulus principle here...

Comment: wait, if its $\mathbb{C}-$linear, you can pill the $i$ out and maybe you can use the hypothesis to get a hold of the real and imaginary parts? like if $z=x+iy$ then $x^2+y^2<4$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is via Parseval's identity for holomorphic functions (see for example [Proof of Parseval's identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540446/proof-of-parsevals-identity)):

Let $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ be the Taylor series of $f$ in $\Bbb D$, then
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|^2 r^{2n}  = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{it})|^2 \, dt \le 4 \, .
$$
Taking the limit $r \to 1$ gives
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|^2 \le 4 \, .
$$
But $|a_2|^2 = |f''(0)/2|^2 = 4$, so that all other Taylor coefficients must be zero.

It follows that $f(z) = 2i z^2$.

Comment: so you're using the fact that since $f$ is analytic it has a convergent power series who converges on the open unit disk? ahhhhh and made use of coefficients!! nicely done!!!!

Comment: @HossienSahebjame: Yes, the Taylor series of a holomorphic function $f$ converges in the largest open disk contained in the domain of $f$.

Comment: This is pretty.  Thank you, as always, @MartinR, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @MartinR just out of curiosity, Hossein mentioned above the idea of using maximum modulus here.  I haven't been able to get it to come out nicely.  Do you see a way to use that?  
On the other hand, using Parseval's identity here is very nice!  Answer accepted!

Comment: @User7238: I don't know. I may be possible, but I haven't found a solution using the MMP yes.

Comment: Interesting.  This is an old qualifier problem from my school from years ago.  I know folks now run into Parseval's identity, so I am familiar with it, but it is not formally discussed in the class now.  So, I suppose I am just trying to figure out whether it 1) was dealt with more back then or 2) they see a different solution  Nonetheless, I really appreciate, as always, all your input!