# Suppose $P(z) = a_0+a_1z + \dots + a_nz^n$ is bounded by 1 for $|z|\leq 1$. Show that $|P(z)|\leq |z^n|$ for all $|z^n|\geq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

As title, I'm wondering is there any way to show that $|P(z)|\leq |z^n|$ for $|z|\geq 1$.
I attempt to divide $|z^n|$ on both side, and get
$$\bigg|\frac{P(z)}{z^n}\bigg| =\bigg |\frac{a_0}{z^n}+\frac{a_1}{z^{n-1}} + \dots a_n\bigg|$$
It's sufficient to show that$$\bigg|\frac{P(z)}{z^n}\bigg|\leq 1$$
But I can't figure out how to prove it, any comment about this question is welcome.

Comment: Use |x+y|<|x|+|y| and the fact that P(1)< 1.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't get the point. But I get $|\frac{P(z)}{z^n}|\leq |a_0| + \dots + |a_n|$ and this is not necessary less or equals to 1.

Comment: ah sorry. i made a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w=1/z$ and note that $P(z)=P(1/w)= a_0+a_1/w + \dots + a_n/w^n$ so $Q(w)=w^nP(1/w)$ is analytic in the unit disc including at $0$. But on the unit circle $|w|=1$ clearly $|Q(w)|=|P(1/w)|=|P(\bar w)| \le 1$ so by maximum modulus we have $|Q(w)| \le 1, |w| \le 1$ which means precisely $|P(z)|/|z|^n \le 1$ for $|z|=|1/w| \ge 1$ and we are done!

Clearly, we get equality at a point iff $Q$ is constant of modulus $1$ so $P(z)=\alpha z^n$ and more generally we can extend this proof to show that if $F$ is a polynomial of degree (at least) $n$ (the degree of $P$) with no zeroes outside the unit disc and $|P(z)| \le |F(z)|$ on the unit circle, then $|P(z)| \le |F(z)|, |z|>1$ with equality at a point iff $P=\alpha F, |\alpha|=1$ as the result above corresponds to $F(z)=z^n$

Answer (score 2):

One has to consider analytic function $f(z) = P(z)/z^n$ on annulus $A(R) = \{{z:|z| >=1 , |z| <= R}\}$ where $R$ is large enough. Also, note that since $|P(z)| <=1$ on $|z| = 1$ one has $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |P(z)|^2 = \sum |a_k|^2$ so $|a_n| <=1$. Now, analytic function takes maximum on boundary and on unit circle, by assumption we know it is not larger than 1. But if $R$ is large enough the values of $|f(z)|$ are about $|a_n|$ which is not larger than 1 as well.

Comment: Can you explain more about why the equality between integral and sum holds?

Comment: @Meep That is Parseval's identity for power series. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540446/proof-of-parsevals-identity

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\vert P(z')\vert \gt \vert z'\vert^n$ for some $z'$ outside $S^1$, the unit circle.
$\implies q(z')=0$ with $q(z):=\delta\cdot P(z) +\alpha \cdot z^n =0$ for some $\delta \in (0,1)$ and some $\alpha \in S^1$.

But for $z\in S^1$ we have $\vert \alpha \cdot z^n\vert = 1\gt \delta\cdot \vert   P(z)\vert=\vert \delta \cdot P(z)\vert$
$\implies q$ has exactly $n$ roots inside $S^1$ by Rouche.  And $q$ is a polynomial with degree at most $n$, with exactly $n$ roots inside the unit circle (hence degree $n$).  Conclude $q(z')=0$ is a contradiction$\implies \vert P(z)\vert \leq \vert z^n\vert$ for all $\vert z\vert \gt 1$.

Comment: Re: the equality conditions, $Q(z):=P(z)-\alpha \cdot z^n$ for some $\alpha \in S^1$ and suppose $Q(z^*) =0$ for some $\vert z^* \vert \gt 1$.  $Q=0$ is easy, so suppose it is non-constant. Apply a rotation, $\beta \in S^1$ to make $P(z^*)$ positive i.e. consider $\beta\cdot Q(z)$.  The open ball $B(z^*,\delta)$ for is open under the image of $\beta \cdot Q$ so there is some $z'\in B(z^*,\delta)$ where $\beta \cdot Q(z')\gt 0$ and for $\delta$ small enough both $\beta\cdot P(z)$ and $\beta\cdot z^n$ have positive real components so $\vert P(z')\vert \gt \vert z'\vert^n$ which is impossible.

Comment: the final sentence in above comment should say "... both $\beta\cdot P(z)$ and $\beta\cdot (\alpha \cdot z^n)$ have positive real components so..."