# Image of imaginary axis under $f$ is either real axis or imaginary axis

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, entire-functions

Let $f$ be a nonzero entire function such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Show that if the image of the imaginary axis under $f$ is contained in a line, then that line must be either the real axis or the imaginary axis.

$\textbf{Approach:}$ Let $L$ be the line containing the image of the imaginary axis. Since $f(0) = 0$, the equation of $L$ must be $ax + by = 0$, for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

How do I prove here that either a = 0 or b = 0?

Comment: I think you meant nonconstant not nonzero

Comment: They’re equivalent if we know $0$ is in the image of $f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Schwarz reflection principle, when $z=it$ for $t\in\mathbb R$, there is $f(it)=\overline{f(-it)}$, so the image of the function must be symmetric about the real axis. Because the only lines symmetric about the real axis and passing the origin ($f(0)=0$) are the real and imaginary axes, we conclude that these are the only possibilities for the image of $f(it)$.

Comment: how are we verifying "the only lines symmetric about the real axis and passing the origin ((0)=0) are the real and imaginary axes"?

Comment: due to symmetry, these lines must either be completely intersecting or perpendicular to the real axis. The perpendicular case can only be the imaginary axis because it must pass through the origin

Answer (score 0):

A nicely visual if somewhat esoteric approach based on winding numbers of non-closed curves:

in $\overline B\big(0, \delta\big)$ for $\delta$ small enough, we have
$f(z) = z^k\cdot g(z)$ and $q(z) = z^k\cdot \lambda $
where $g$ is locally non-zero analytic and $g(0) = \lambda\in \mathbb R-\big\{0\big\}$

define $\gamma:[0, \frac{1}{4}]\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ given by
$\gamma(t)=r \cdot \exp\big(2\pi i\cdot t\big)$ for $r\in \big(0,\delta\big)$
note that by continuity of $g$, for all $r$ small enough we have
$\big \vert f\big(\gamma(t)\big)-q\big(\gamma(t)\big)\big \vert=r^k \cdot \big\vert g\big(\gamma(t)\big)-\lambda\big\vert \lt r^k \cdot \vert\lambda\vert$

Then comparing winding numbers
$\big \vert n\big(f\circ \gamma, 0\big)-n\big(q\circ \gamma, 0\big)\big \vert \lt \frac{ \epsilon}{\pi \cdot(1-\epsilon)}$
where we know the Left Hand Side is constant since $f$ maps the 'line segment' [without end points] given by all points $d\cdot i$ for $d\in (0,\delta)$ into a half line (i.e. a connected subset of a line that does not contain zero, and this forms a locally constant angle vs the relevant half of the real line) and the upper bound comes from the **Key Lemma** at the end of this:
[A complex analysis proof of the extremal case of Bernstein's inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4688731/a-complex-analysis-proof-of-the-extremal-case-of-bernsteins-inequality/4728399#4728399)
Since the upper bound may be made arbitrarily small by selecting $r$ small enough, we conclude the constant is zero, i.e. if $k$ is odd then $f$ sends the imaginary line to the imaginary line, and if $k$ is even then $f$ sends the imaginary line to the real line.