Equality in Bernstein's inequality
Let $p(z)$ be a complex polynomial of degree $n$ then according to Bernstein's inequality,
$\underset{|z|=1}{\max}|p^\prime(z)|\leq n \underset{|z|=1}{\max}|p(z)|.$
The equality holds if $p(z)=az^n.$
I want to show that the equality holds only if $p(z)=az^n. $
Please suggest some hints to proceed.

Which method do you use for proving Bernstein? Usually equality cases are seen when looking at equality in the method inequalities.

for example, if you use the Feijer kernel method of proof, that immediately leads you to equality only for $e^{-int}P(e^{it})$ being constant, so $P(e^{it})=ce^{int}$ etc

I gave a winding number based proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4688731/a-complex-analysis-proof-of-the-extremal-case-of-bernsteins-inequality/
